# How to define boolean value inside a function definition in Python?

Tags: python, variables, boolean

How would I define a Boolean variable declared in the scope of a function?

I have defined the variable `pass = True` in the function below, and set its value in an `if` statement within the function definition:

```
def test(array, n): # Define the function test with input parameters array and n
    pass = True # Initialize variable pass to the boolean value True
    for i in n: # For n number of times, perform the following operation using i as a counter
        for j in range(i+1,n): # Increment from i+1 to n using j as a counter
        if(array[i] == array[j]):   # If the ith element in array equals the jth element, execute the following code
                                                # If one element is equivalent to any subsequent
                                                # elements of the array, set pass = true
            pass = False # define pass as false

return pass # return pass
```

Comment: This code looks correct, although some of the lines are not indented properly. Is that your problem or did you copy/paste wrong and have another question?

Comment: up to the fact, that: 1. you do not use parensis around if statements in python. 2. "pass" is a keyword in python, and you are trying to overwrite it, choose different name for the variable

Comment: @lejlot `pass` is a keyword, so this program won't even compile.

Comment: You have some other indentation issues in your code (beyond just the last line, your `if` statement isn't indented properly from the second `for` statement).

Comment: Don't use `pass` as a variable name, it is a [**keyword** in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: Much simpler and more efficient to `return True` by default and `return False` in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Besides some indentation issues, which I assume are due to posting on SO and not due to the real code being mis-indented, the problem is that [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) is a reserved word in python - it's the null operation. If you replace it with a legal identifier (e.g., `shouldPass`), you should be fine:

```
def test(array, n): # Define the function test with input parameters array and n
    shouldPass = True # Initialize variable shouldPass to the boolean value True
    for i in n: # For n number of times, perform the following operation using i as a counter
        for j in range(i+1,n): # Increment from i+1 to n using j as a counter
            if array[i] == array[j]:   # If the ith element in array equals the jth element, execute the following code
                                                # If one element is equivalent to any subsequent
                                                # elements of the array, set shouldPass = true
                shouldPass = False # define shouldPass as false

    return shouldPass # return shouldPass
```

Comment: And `n` also doesn't looks like an iterable, they are looping over it and then passing it to `range()`. I guess they meant: `for i in range(n):`

Comment: I didn't delve into the "business logic" of the function, just the syntactic problems.

Comment: Considering they haven't cared to post any traceback at all, their next comment is going to be: "It is still not working". ;-)